# Is there a way to replicate the consistency of chain pizza "garlic dipping sauces" easily?

Tags: sauce, restaurant-mimicry

Replicating the taste of "garlic dipping sauce" from various pizza chains is very easy, essentially start with melted butter, and add garlic powder and salt to taste.

While this nails the flavour, the problem is you end up with something that has the consistency and melting properties of butter, instead of the margarine most chains use as the base.

Is there an easy way to replicate the creamy consistency at room temperature, which will liquefy just from the latent heat of sitting in a pizza box?  Preferably without using margarine?

Answer (score 1):

Different pizza chains in different places use different sauces, and we don't know where you are. But your description is something to work towards. As an example of the variety, it's not the consistency you're looking for, but a thicker example that works well is garlic mayo

Aiming for your description, I'd try garlic butter thinned with olive oil.  Not fancy olive oil, just the one I use for frying (sautéing) some things, describe as "medium flavour".  But similar sauces I've had haven't seemed like 100% oil, so they probably have water and an emulsifier in them as well.  They're not always fully emulsified, and may need a bit of a stir, so adding a little water as well as the oil to butter might be acceptable.  As a start for experimenting, I'd add olive oil at 25% of the weight of the melted butter, and water at 10%, beating together.  When doing similar things I (at least) lightly cook the garlic in the butter; puréed garlic is [supposed to act as an emulsifier](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-does-emulsify-mean-480592) which will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Little Caesar's doesn't seem to use margarine:

> **Caesar Dips® Butter Garlic Flavor:**
>
> **Soybean Oil, Fully Hydrogenated Soybean Oil**, Salt, Soy Lecithin, Artificial and Natural Flavors, Beta Carotene (For Color), Hydrolyzed Soy Protein, Autolyzed Yeast
> Extract, Contains 2% or Less of Salt, Artificial and Natural Flavor, Xanthan Gum, Propylene Glycol Alginate, With Sorbic Acid and Phosphoric Acid (Preservatives), and
> Calcium Disodium EDTA (To Protect Quality).

Page 5 of their [menu](https://littlecaesars.com/static/1652798254-cr0019464_aa_nutriflyer_arodr_4c_final_june2022.pdf)

Comment: Isn't "hydrogenated oil" synonymous with Margarine?

Comment: Not always, but in this case, yes.

Comment: You still put trans fats in food in the US? 15 years ago in the UK it was assumed there was going to be a ban following public outcry & all the manufacturers removed them entirely. The ban never actually came, but the trend continued.

Comment: @Tetsujin IIRC, _fully_-hydrogenated fats can't be trans. (‘Cis’ and ‘trans’ refer to the positioning of groups around a double-bond; but hydrogenation converts double-bonds into single ones, so only _partially_ hydrogenated fats can be trans.) I'm guessing that's why they specify ‘fully’.

Comment: I'm no chemist, all I know is they got rid of all that stuff here 15 years ago.